# How to enlarge the edit-box size of the login screen of fedora?

Tags: linux, fedora, kde, login, gui

My macbook with retina display runs fedora-20 KDE spin. The annoying issue is:

**On the default login screen, the edit-boxes for username and password look too small to input.**

Is there a simple way to customize the size of these edit-boxes?

Comment: If you don't get any help here, I'd try posting at the kde forums. They are very helpful.